# Azure AD B2C customizing UI elements inserted by Azure

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I have read the documentation of Azure AD B2C and how to customize UI using templates.
I tested it, it works.

However, I want to customize the look and feel of the very fields inserted by Azure in the "api" div.

Is there an exhaustive list of css classes we can override for customizing the UI?
Or is there other ways to customize the UI / UX of what is inserted by Azure?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Target the HTML elementIds of the elements inserted into the div api node and write CSS or JS for them.

Comment: Suri : That's the thing: on my template rendered, the page source only display a massive javascript. Where do I get the name of the html elements ? Is there a comprehensive example available somewhere?

Comment: Inspect the page, all the IDs are present. If you use custom policy, the html element ids are the same as your claim names. No, there is no list available that you ask for.

Comment: Use the browsers dev tools, and look at HTML elements tab. Do not view page source.